# Use HTML lists in graphviz (dot) graphs

Tags: graphviz, dot

I would like to integrate HTML lists (`<ul><li>...</li></ul>`) in the text label of my Graphviz nodes. Something of the sort:

```
digraph {

  a [label="<ul><li>My item</li><li>My item 2<ul><li>My nested item</li></ul></li></ul>"] 
  b [label="A node without a list"]

  a -> b
}
```

I think this is, so far, not possible to do it because the Graphviz language supports only a subset of the HTML vocabulary (see https://graphviz.org/doc/info/shapes.html#html).

I tried to code a very hand-made solution composed of nested tables (for indentation) with • symbols (for lists bullets). However, this is a nightmare to code and not very easy to tune/prettify.

Do some of you alredy tackled this problem and have some suggestions?

I use graphViz because this is very handy to position nodes "in the best configuration" depending on their connections and size. As Graphviz is not a requirement, **I am open to any proposal to draw nodes with "full HTML"-like labels that are automatically positionned based on their connections and size.**

Answer (score 2):

The "easiest" way to get the complete capabilities of HTML would seem to be to write each label in a separate HTML file and then convert the HTML to SVG (best) or png, jpeg, ... (good enough) and include these into your Graphviz input as images (https://www.graphviz.org/docs/attrs/image/) files.
**Imagemagick** (https://imagemagick.org/script/formats.php) seems to be able to convert HTML to SVG.